# sort big amount of records by date

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, programming-languages, date-sorting

I got 10700 record I need to sort them fast as possible 
I've been reading about types of sorting algorithms but got lost I didn't know what's the best to choose: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

EDIT 1:
I need to write down a code that calculates the time of executing the algorithm

EDIT 1-2 : Is there any language that has the functionality of sorting and calculating the time of sorting it ?

And one more question is the language used to implement the algorithms affects the speed ? 
(e.g if I used c++ will it be faster than java or .Net lang. ??  )

Note this not a Home Work.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you ask for "how many seconds it will take" which heavily depend on hardware, without giving any information about it. also, if you did, no one will make this benchmark for you, you should just benchmark it yourself.

Comment: Your question is not really answerable. The best choice depends on a whole lot of factors, including what environment/language you're most familiar with, and what factors you want to optimize for (time only, memory, balance both? Worried about skewed data impacting the timings?) "Will it be faster" depends on how it's coded. BTW, 10k records is rather small, probably too small to make a noticeable difference between reasonable algorithms on a modern platform.

Comment: @Mat amen to that - an algorithm selection criterion that sometimes pops up (too) late in the process is whether the sort is stable, it's best to think about that from the start as well.

Comment: Ok , what's the best choice in factor of speed (complexity ) as the quick sort normal case in nLog(n) , and how to calculate the execution time of the algorithm independent of Hardware ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless this is a homework problem, don't implement your own sorting algorithm.

Use the one already provided by your development environment - it'll be robust, debugged, and almost certainly faster than anything you'll write yourself.

FWIW, the `Sort()` method on `List<T>` in .NET uses a QuickSort.

The actual environment (C++ vs .NET vs Java) will have negligable impact, unless you're doing this in an absurdly small amount of memory. Use whatever you have experience with.

Comment: Ok I need to calculate the execution time how ?

Comment: @xsari as explained on the wikipedia page you read, many sorting algorithms' execution time is variable, depending on the order of the input dataset.  Doing test runs with the expected data quantity and various random cases and special cases (pre-sorted, inverted, etc) should give you a pretty good idea about how long the selected sorting algorithm will take to sort your input.

Comment: To *measure* the elapsed execution time, use the `StopWatch` class in .NET. Calculating the execution time in advance is nigh on impossible - even if you could predict the number of required CPU cycles, you'd also need to factor in all the other programs running on the machine and predict (in advance) which of them will make demands on CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

This chunk of code in Java shows how you could determine at least some of the figures you're after  :

```
public class Main {

    private static long test (double[] tosort) {
        Date begin = new Date();
        Arrays.sort(tosort);
        Date end = new Date();
        return end.getTime() - begin.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] tosort = new double[10700];

        for (int jj=0;jj<10;jj++) {
            for (int ii=0;ii<tosort.length;ii++) {
                tosort[ii] = Math.random();
            }
            System.out.println("Random data " + test(tosort));
        }

        for (int jj=0;jj<10;jj++) {
            for (int ii=0;ii<tosort.length;ii++) {
                tosort[ii] = ii;
            }
            System.out.println("Presorted data " + test(tosort));
        }

        for (int jj=0;jj<10;jj++) {
            for (int ii=0;ii<tosort.length;ii++) {
                tosort[ii] = tosort.length - ii;
            }
            System.out.println("Inverted data " + test(tosort));
        }

    }

}
```

Fyi, only my computer each run that code executed stayed below 1 millisecond spent in the sorting routine, I had to increase the data size 100 fold to get some meaningful data.

- This piece of code makes entire abstraction of things like the time the comparator code needs (the elements are primitive doubles, comparing other objects will probably take a whole lot more time)
- once the just in time compiler has figured out the code, it should become a bit faster as well
- you could easily add test runs with alternative sorting algorithms and see how those behave

These figures will vary in function of hardware, input data type, load on your computer, etc, but you can at least get a feeling for what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ***implement*** any algorithm (unless this is homework). Every language has its sorting functions, and they are pretty efficient. For example, in C++ you'd use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) which on many implementation uses quick sort (and insertion sort if the number of elements is small).

Comment: In most modern implementations, I'd expect `std::sort` to be implemented as an Introsort; that normally acts like a Quicksort, but if the recursion gets too deep, it switches to a Heapsort.